# Error de Sintaxis en laravel

Tags: php, formularios, php7, laravel-blade

Laravel 5.2.
Estoy intentando crear un nuevo registro en mi tabla fidelización, para que me seleccione el cliente y me seleccione el menu mediante un foreach y me sale este error en la linea 50 y pues no especifica realmente donde es.
Ayuda por favor.

ErrorException en b84244b0dbad0f35077dbebbf01f14e65bf9c274.php línea 50 :
Error de análisis: error de sintaxis, final inesperado del archivo (Ver: C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ Monkey \ resources \ views \ almacen \ fidelizaccion \ create.blade.php)

1. Este es mi Controlador

```
<?php

namespace freeSystem\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use freeSystem\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use freeSystem\Http\Requests\FidelizaccionFormRequest;
use freeSystem\Fidelizaccion;
use DB;

class FidelizaccionController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request)
        {
            $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
            $fidelizacciones=DB::table('fidelizaccion as f')
            ->join('cliente as c', 'f.idCliente', '=', 'c.idCliente')
             ->join('menu as m', 'f.idPlato', '=', 'm.idPlato')
             ->select( 'f.idFidelizaccion', 'c.nombre',
              'c.cedula', 'f.fecha', 'm.descripcion', 
              'm.valor', 'm.tipos', 'f.estado')
            ->where('c.nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('f.idFidelizaccion','desc')
            ->paginate(7);
            return view('almacen.fidelizaccion.index',["fidelizacciones"=>$fidelizacciones,"searchText"=>$query]);
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $clientes=DB::table('cliente')->where('estado', '=', '1')->get();
        $menus=DB::table('menu')->where('estado', '=', '1')->get();
        return view("almacen.fidelizaccion.create", ["clientes"=>$clientes, "menus"=>$menus]);
    }
    public function store (FidelizaccionFormRequest $request)
    {
        $fidelizaccion = new Fidelizaccion;
        $fidelizaccion->idCliente=$request->get('idCliente');
        $fidelizaccion->idPlato=$request->get('idPlato');
        $fidelizaccion->fecha=$request->get('fecha');
        $fidelizaccion->estado='Activo';
        $fidelizaccion->save();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/fidelizaccion');

    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        
        return view("almacen.fidelizaccion.show",["fidelizaccion"=>Fidelizaccion::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //para selecionar un solo id en especifico
        $fidelizaccion=Fidelizaccion::findOrFail($id);
        $clientes=DB::table('cliente')->where('estado', '=', 'Activo')->get();
        $menus=DB::table('menu')->where('estado', '=', 'Activo')->get();
        return view("almacen.fidelizaccion.edit",["fidelizaccion"=>$fidelizaccion, "clientes"=>$clientes, "menus"=>$menus ]);
    }
    public function update(FidelizaccionFormRequest $request,$id)
    {
        $fidelizaccion=Fidelizaccion::findOrFail($id);
        $fidelizaccion->idCliente=$request->get('idCliente');
        $fidelizaccion->idPlato=$request->get('idPlato');
        $fidelizaccion->fecha=$request->get('fecha');
        $fidelizaccion->estado='Activo';
        $fidelizaccion->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/fidelizaccion');
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $fidelizaccion=Fidelizaccion::findOrFail($id);
        $fidelizaccion->estado='Inactivo';
        $fidelizaccion->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/fidelizaccion');
    }
}
```

```
2. Estes es mi create 'create.blade.php

  @extends ('layouts.admin')
  @section ('contenido')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Nueva Fidelizaccion</h3>
            @if (count($errors)>0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif

            {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'almacen/fidelizaccion','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
            {{Form::token()}}
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Menu</label>
                  <select name="idPlato" class="form-control">
                  @foreach($menus as $men)
                  <option value="{{$men->idPlato}}">{{$men->descripcion}}</option>
                  @enforeach
                  </select>
            </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cliente</label>
                  <select name="idPlato" class="form-control">
                  @foreach($clientes as $cli)
                  <option value="{{$cli->idCliente}}">{{$cli->nombre}}</option>
                  @enforeach
                  </select>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                <input type="text" name="fecha" required value="{{old(fecha)}}" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha...">
            </div>
         
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
            </div>

            {!!Form::close()!!}     
            
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: `@enforeach` debería ser `@endforeach`

Comment: Y tienes otro en `{{old(fecha)}}`. Fíjate que a los errores de sintaxis, cualquier IDE decente te los marca. Para el caso de las directivas de blade, tal vez tengas que instalarle un plugin, te recomiendo que busques uno, pues te facilitará la vida

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude solucionar uno de los problemas